# Exception thrown when trying to deploy CAS maven overlay

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, jboss7.x, cas

I'm trying to setup a CAS server locally in Jboss. i'm trying to deploy the maven overlay described in this link.

https://github.com/UniconLabs/simple-cas4-overlay-template

and when i'm trying to deploy the cas.war file i got few errors and i managed to fix them by adding following dependencies.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now i'm getting this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class  [org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler

I tried to find a dependency having this class but I didn't find. What am i doing wrong ?

My ultimate goal is to integrate CAS with Sprint security. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was due to not specifying "com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler" under modules in jboss wildfly.

To fix the issue add the following under paths in `/modules/system/layers/base/sun/jdk/main/module.xml`:

```
<path name="com/sun/net/httpserver"/>
```